# What can I do with my index data?

Tags: time-series

I have an index (similar to say, the Consumer Price Index) which contains a number of weighted items. I have time-series data for each of the items that comprise this index, in addition to the index itself.

Ideally I would like to find out what is going on in my index - the most important 'drivers' of change over time, the most volatile components, and so on.

If I'm not wrong, a standard regression analysis is not very useful since the weight of each item in the index is already defined. What else can I do here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the weights, and the weights are constant, then as you said I don't know that any analysis that attributes % change in index to one of its components will be useful. (are the weights constant, or will they vary with the values of the components?)

Therefore I'd recommend that you do some standard exploratory data analysis on each time series. There are many resources you can find if you search for this. I'll give a few specific ideas here based on what you said:

- For volatility, calculate the coefficient of variation (Std Dev / Mean)
- If # of components is not too high (less than 100) plot and visually examine each one
- Perform decomposition to detect which ones have trends and/or seasonality